# loading multiple relations in one query PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, ecto

There are 4 tables.

1. Snapmails

   - User
   - Snapmail Cameras

     - Cameras

when a user adds a snapmail, let say user's id is `41` and snapmail he created has `id` of 1. and He created snapmail for 5 cameras, and they have ids as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

now snapmail in db will look like

```
ID | user_id | 
1  |   41    |
```

and snapmail_cameras will have

```
ID | camera_id | snapmail_id
 1 |     1     |     1
 2 |     2     |     1
 3 |     3     |     1
 4 |     4     |     1
 5 |     5     |     1
```

I am trying to get all snapmails which is pretty simple, 
`select * from snapmails` but I want to have 2 more things in this.

User's name and Camera'name.

I have tried this.

```
SELECT sm.*, u.firstname || ' ' || u.lastname as fullname,cam.name
FROM snapmails as sm
INNER JOIN users as u ON sm.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN snapmail_cameras as sc ON sm.id = sc.snapmail_id
LEFT JOIN cameras as cam ON sc.camera_id = cam.id
```

This gives me what I want but in a different way. I want to get a snapmail from db such as

```
 ID  | fullname | camera_names
 1   | Junaid F.|  Camera1, Camera2, Camera3
```

but my query is giving me as

```
 ID  | fullname | camera_name
 1   | Junaid F.|  Camera1
 1   | Junaid F.|  Camera2
 1   | Junaid F.|  Camera3
 1   | Junaid F.|  Camera4
 1   | Junaid F.|  Camera5
```

camera table has a column `name` and user's table has 2 columns `firstname` and `lastname`. My query is giving me all results but one row for each camera but I want to have one row with all camera names. is that possible?

UPDATE:
I am working in `Ecto` Will that possible to wrap this all in Ecto Query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `string_agg`:

```
SELECT sm.id, u.firstname || ' ' || u.lastname as fullname, string_agg(cam.name, ',')
FROM snapmails as sm
INNER JOIN users as u ON sm.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN snapmail_cameras as sc ON sm.id = sc.snapmail_id
LEFT JOIN cameras as cam ON sc.camera_id = cam.id
group by 1, 2
```

Comment: what is group by 1, 2?

Comment: a bit of SQL slang (not best practice anyways). It means group by the first and second columns. You can go with `group by sm.id, fullname` too